# Phonegap + AngularJS + WP7

Tags: angularjs, windows-phone-7, cordova

I'm working with Phonegap and AngularJS and want to put my app on windows mobile phone 7. But angularjs ist not working by using data binding, e.g. {{service.greeting}}. I'm getting no error, it just shows nothing on my device. What's wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran to similar issue myself. It's because Windows Phone returns current URL as `x-wmapp0:www/index.html` which Angular cannot handle.

AFAIK it's not fixed yet, see Angular [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2303) for further info.